# jQuery AJAX GIF preloader for CSS Background-Image

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, preloader, css

I've been using jQuery AJAX preloading GIF images for a while now, by this code:

```
$("#images").html("<img id='loader' src='../img/ajax-loader.gif' />");
```

What i'm trying to do now is, how can i implement this same effect (a spinning wheel or similar) to preload CSS background images not just img tags?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Once the browser has loaded an image into cache, it can retrieve it from cache for img tags or for css backgrounds.  So I believe if you continue doing exactly what you are doing to preload images, then you can use that to preload background images.  In other words, if you have this css:

```
#SomeElement { background: url('../img/whatever.gif'); }
```

then you can do this to preload it:

```
$("#images").html("<img id='loader' src='../img/whatever.gif' />");
```

I am not entirely familiar with your technique for preloading however, so I could be wrong...

Comment: Thta is the technique i'm using. I'm using that one line, then the proper ajax loaded images are filling the #images element...

Answer (score 0):

for img tag, obviously you can capture onload event, but when you are dealing with css background images, I don't think and never heard capture the onload event for css background image.